# Create combinations from a list and 3 ranges using itertools

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations

I have the following:

```
a_list = [A,B,C]
r1 = range(1,5)
r2 = range(1,5)
r3 = range(1,5)
```

I would like to be able to find the various combinations of the elements in this list against the ranges. For example:

```
combi1 = [A, B, C, C, C]
combi2 = [A, A, B, C, C]
combi3 = [A, A, A, B, C]
combi4 = [A, B, B, C, C]
```

Etc.

I am able to do so if there were only 2 `range`, but I'm not sure how to fit 3 `range` in.

```
inc = range(1, 5)
desc = range(5, 1, -1)
combis = [list(itertools.chain(*(itertools.repeat(elem, n) for elem, n in zip(list, [i,j])))) for i,j in zip(inc,desc)]
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
def all_exist(avalue, bvalue):
    return all(any(x in y for y in bvalue) for x in avalue)

combins = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(a_list, 5)
combins_list = [list(i) for i in combins]
for c in combins_list:
    if all_exist(a_list, c) == True:
        print c
```

output:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more how you derive the output lists?

Comment: Maybe start by *unwinding* the comprehension into nested for loops to make it easier to look at. And provide a written description of what that comprehension is doing or is supposed to do.

Comment: Please correct the errors in yor example code.

Comment: I genuinely fail to see, what the operation is that connects the list with the three ranges. And if one range increments from 1 to 4 and the second decrements from 5 to 2, what is the third range supposed to represent? Your  example code doesn't help. It produces lists with six elements and you overwrite the builtin function `list()` with your variable `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@doyz. I think this is may be what you are looking for :

From a list `abc = ['A','B','C']`, you want to obtain its various *combinations with replacement*. Python has built-in `itertools` to do this.

```
import itertools

abc = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

combins = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(abc, 5);
combins_list = [list(i) for i in combins];

print(combins_list[0:10]);
```

This is the first 10 combinations with replacement :

```
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'], \
 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C'], \
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], ['A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

If you want to include all elements in `abc`, here is one way, that also includes the permutations :

```
import itertools
abc = ['A', 'B', 'C']; 
combins = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(abc, 5); 
combins_list = list(combins);
combins_all =[];
for i in combins_list:
    if len(set(i))==len(abc):
        combins_all.append(i);
print(combins_all);

include_permutations=[];
for i in combins_all:
    permut = list(itertools.permutations(i));
    include_permutations.append(permut);
print(include_permutations);
```

Is this okay?

*Note : `itertools.combinations_woth_replacement` and `itertools.permutations` do not result in a list, or tuple, but a different object itself, so you can't treat it as those.

Comment: Hey @Arief, thanks! but i would like each item A, B, C to appear in the combination list at least once, meaning that there can't be all As, or 4As and 1B

Comment: Hey @Arief, i managed to fix it with the solution above. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: @doyz nice. I edited the answer, but forgot to notify you.